# How to host python webserver giving access to all images in a directory

Tags: python, httpserver

I would like to extract the python built-in webserver to list all images in a directory on the index page and also server the images themselves.

So for a directory of the following form:

```
my_images/
├── img1.png
├── img2.png
└── results
    └── result.png
```

The index page would look like

```
Index of my_images

img1.png (link)
img2.png (link)
results/ (link)
```

Can this be done easily with the python `http.server`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `cd` into the folder `my_images`, then do `python -m http.server`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn"t notice, that it can do this already!